# Calculate $\int_{\mathbb{R}^n}|\langle x, a \rangle|^p e^{-\lVert x \rVert^2}$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration

Let $a\in\mathbb{R}^n$, $p>-1$ and $\langle {,} \rangle$ the usual inner product. I wanted to use a coordinate change but the inner product is a problem. Someoe gave me a hint of changing the base, but I don't know how to do that

Comment: MathJax hint: `\lVert` and `\rVert` should provide better visual results than `||`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a sketch whose details you should fill in. For any appropriately integrable function $f$ you have from Fubini's theorem that
$$\int_{\mathbf R^n} f(x) \, dx = \int_0^\infty \int_{|x| = r} f(x) \, dS^{n-1}x dr$$
where $dS^{n-1}$ is the surface element on the unit sphere $\mathbf S^{n-1}$. Use the change of variable $x = r \omega$ in the inner integral to write
$$\int_{|x| = r} f(x) \, dS^{n-1}x = r^{n-1} \int_{|\omega|=1} f(r\omega) \, dS^{n-1} \omega.$$

In your case let $f(x) = |\langle x,a\rangle|^p e^{-|x|^2}.$ Then for $\omega$ with $|\omega| = 1$ it follows that
$$f(r\omega) = r^p|\langle \omega,a\rangle|^p e^{-r^2}.$$ Consequently
$$\int_{\mathbf R^n} f(x) \, dx = \int_0^\infty r^{n-1+p} e^{-r^2} \int_{|\omega| = 1} |\langle \omega,a\rangle|^p \, dS^{n-1}\omega dr.$$
The innermost integral is some constant whose value depends on $a$. The outer integral (up to that constant) is $$\int_0^\infty r^{n-1+p} e^{-r^2} \, dr$$ which converges. Is it possible that the inner integral is infinite?

Comment: You should point out that the inner integral is a some constant whose value depends only on $|a|$. Your notation $dS{n-1}\omega$ is most unusual for some of us.

Comment: @TedShifrin  Thanks Ted. I'm not too concerned about dependence on $a$ vs $|a|$ but I'm curious about your second comment and would like to make this answer as clear as I can. I'm familiar with using (say) $dH^{n-1}$ for the $n-1$ dimensional Hausdorff measure, and in a more elementary context replacing it with $dS^{n-1}$ for the surface measure on a sphere - this makes it look more like the $dS$ that students are likely to remember in calculus textbooks.

Comment: Yeah, but the $\omega$ following it looks like it's a (vector-valued) function to be integrated, whereas you intend it to just be part of the element of surface area notation. Maybe a subscript?

Comment: I see what you are saying, but I think the notation of integrating a function of $z$ using a measure $\mu$ as $\displaystyle \int f(z) \, d\mu z$ is well-established, similar to writing $dr$ rather than $d(r)$ or $d_r$, when $\mu$ is a surface measure in $\mathbf R^n$.

Comment: No, we ordinarily write $d\mu(z)$ if we include the variable explicitly. When I looked at your equation, I truly thought you were integrating a function, as one might actually do here with spherical integrals. Anyhow, I’m just suggesting that others may be confused, as well.